# Query Optimization with Indexes

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, multi-index

I am needing some assistance on optimizing this WordPress/WooCommerce query:

```
SELECT
    p.ID AS order_id
    ,DATE(p.post_date) AS order_date
    ,SUBSTR(comment_content,17) AS csr
    ,SUBSTR(p.post_status,4) AS order_status
    ,UCASE(CONCAT((SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_billing_first_name' and wp_postmeta.post_id = p.ID),' ',(SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_billing_last_name' and wp_postmeta.post_id = p.ID))) AS customer
    ,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT order_item_name ORDER BY order_item_name ASC SEPARATOR ', ') FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_id = p.ID AND order_item_type = 'line_item' GROUP BY order_id) AS products
    ,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(serial_number,'',serial_feature_code)) FROM wp_custom_serial WHERE wp_custom_serial.order_id = p.ID GROUP BY wp_custom_serial.order_id) AS serials 
FROM
    wp_posts AS p
    INNER JOIN wp_comments AS c ON p.ID = c.comment_post_ID
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
    
WHERE
    p.post_type = 'shop_order'
    AND comment_content LIKE 'Order placed by%'
GROUP BY p.ID
ORDER BY SUBSTR(comment_content,17) ASC, p.post_date DESC;
```

I do not understand what `EXPLAIN` is telling me and need some guidance on how to speed it up. Can someone describe what, in the `EXPLAIN` response, indicates where my issue is and where to look for answers?

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | c | NULL | ALL | comment_post_ID | NULL | NULL | NULL | 20452 | 11.11 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | PRIMARY | p | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY,post_name,type_status_date,post_parent,post_author | PRIMARY | 8 | db.c.comment_post_ID | 1 | 50.00 | Using where |
| 1 | PRIMARY | pm | NULL | ref | post_id | post_id | 8 | db.c.comment_post_ID | 33 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | wp_postmeta | NULL | ref | post_id,meta_key | post_id | 8 | func | 33 | 2.26 | Using where |
| 3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | wp_postmeta | NULL | ref | post_id,meta_key | post_id | 8 | func | 33 | 2.30 | Using where |
| 4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | wp_woocommerce_order_items | NULL | ref | order_id | order_id | 8 | func | 2 | 10.00 | Using where |
| 5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | wp_custom_serial | NULL | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 5160 | 10.00 | Using where; Using filesort |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queries are processed in distinct stages.  The first clauses processed are the FROM, then WHERE, and then the SELECT clause.  Those dependent subqueries mean that for each row that you "have" after processing the FROM and WHERE clauses you are running separate, new subqueries for **each row** of those results.  In your case you are doing that times four.

You can usually rework this to move these queries out of the SELECT clause and into the FROM clause.

Taking one column you have, the `serials` column, I think you would want to move that into the FROM clause in a way like this

```
SELECT p.ID                                                                                  AS order_id
     , DATE(p.post_date)                                                                     AS order_date
     , SUBSTR(comment_content, 17)                                                           AS csr
     , SUBSTR(p.post_status, 4)                                                              AS order_status
     , UCASE(CONCAT((SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value
                     FROM wp_postmeta
                     WHERE meta_key = '_billing_first_name' and wp_postmeta.post_id = p.ID), ' ',
                    (SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value
                     FROM wp_postmeta
                     WHERE meta_key = '_billing_last_name' and wp_postmeta.post_id = p.ID))) AS customer
     , (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT order_item_name ORDER BY order_item_name ASC SEPARATOR ', ')
        FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items
        WHERE order_id = p.ID
          AND order_item_type = 'line_item'
        GROUP BY order_id)                                                                   AS products
     , serials_sub.serials
FROM wp_posts AS p
         INNER JOIN wp_comments AS c ON p.ID = c.comment_post_ID
         INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
         LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT p.ID as post_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(cs.serial_number, '', cs.serial_feature_code)) AS serials
            FROM wp_custom_serial cs
            JOIN wp_posts AS p ON cs.order_id = p.ID
            WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order'
             AND comment_content LIKE 'Order placed by%'
            GROUP BY cs.order_id
         ) as serials_sub ON serials_sub.post_id = p.ID
WHERE p.post_type = 'shop_order'
  AND comment_content LIKE 'Order placed by%'
GROUP BY p.ID
ORDER BY SUBSTR(comment_content, 17) ASC, p.post_date DESC;
```

The difference here is that instead of separate queries being performed for each row, a single subquery is used in the initial FROM clause.  So while perhaps looking more unwieldy, in fact this will give you much better performance.

Following this pattern for the other subqueries I think will resolve your issues.

If interested here is the documentation on the EXPLAIN.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execution-plan-information.html

And I recommend the book [High Performance MySQL](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/high-performance-mysql/9781449332471/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Alden W. It makes sense as you described it, but it's throwing an error:
```query 1 ERROR: Unknown column 'serials.post_id' in 'on clause'```
so I'll see if I can track that down.

Comment: Yes, that should be `serials_sub`.  I had fixed that but you beat me to it :-)

Comment: Found it! It should have been ```ON serials_sub.post_id = p.ID```

Took the query down from 229.5s to 19.5s – thank you!

Comment: Happy to help, for sure.  And was that with still the other dependent subqueries in there still? or did you comment those out?  Because if you fix those up also in the same way you should see similar scale of improvement on top of that.

Comment: Yes, I ran it just as you had with the exception of the ‘’’serials_sub’’’. 

Thank you not only for helping, but for teaching - I learned something new!

Comment: Thanks again @Alden W! I have read the documentation (who would have thought) and actually recall having that book which I'm looking for now.

Comment: Jut wanted to let you know that I finally got around to playing with the other sub queries and got it down to 732ms. Learn a lot and can't thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

- The outer wp_postmeta does not seem to be used.  Remove the JOIN if possible.
- Hiding information in the middle of strings leads to `SUBSTR()` usage, which is inefficient.
- The `GROUP BY p.ID` seems to be unnecessary.
- The plugin [*WP Index Improvements*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/) would help with some parts.